# store previous 10 locations in android location application

Tags: android, location, storage

Hi 
I am new to android and developing a android app which captures the user's location. I need to store the last 10 known locations and display them to the user on button click. So please help me how to do this..

The last 10 locations needs to be updated and shown to the users. I should display only 10 recent locations

Answer (score 0):

how about saving the 10 locations in an array and then display all the elements in the array? if you want to store the locations on the device you can read about data-storage in android here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to develop some `Service` which will request user's location via `LocationManager`'s `requestLocationUpdates` method.

Location data must be saved somewhere (i.e. in file or in SQLite database (see `SQLiteOpenHelper`, `ContentProvider`)) and when displayed from main application activity.